# How can edge rings be selected in a predictable way?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

When trying to select multiple edge-rings <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd> sometimes loops get selected in the one (green) way or the other (red) way. 
I couldn't derive a general rule.

How can two or more face-rings following one direction be selected ?

(Easy to reproduce with a default torus mesh.)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The direction is determined from the edge your mouse is over when you click.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> clicking an edge will select the face loop perpendicular to the edge clicked:

[image]

[image]