# How to control which edge loop is selected?

Tags: selection-tools, edges

Sometimes when I'm in edit mode, there will be maybe 3 or 4 possible edge loops I can select. About 95% of the time it selects the edge loop which I don't want.

Is there anyway to control which edge loop gets selected when I right click on the same vertex?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3038/599

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Which edge loop gets selected when pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> is controlled by the *edge* clicked, not the vertex.

Click an edge which belongs in the edge loop you want to select in order to select that loop:

[image]

Note that the edge clicked also becomes the *active* edge (white).

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty much the exact same thing reworded for people who are new. And it's for faces.
Blender calculates which loop to select based on the distance from the center of your click. If it's to the left or right, it'll select the horizontal; up or down of the center, and blender selects the vertical loop.

It really depends on which *side* you right-click on. if I was trying to select the horizontal loop, I'd click on the spot right in between the two faces.

[image]

Same for vertical, just click on the top edge.

[image]

**Edit**; it's the opposite for edge or vertex.

Comment: Note that this the opposite for *Edge* or *Vertex* modes.

Comment: ^correct, but Gandalf had that covered.