# Face/Edge loop selection precision

Tags: selection-tools

When I use face/edge loop selection,every now and then the selection goes off in the wrong direction. See image below. I was trying to select vertical face loops only, but a horizontal one got selected. This causes me to Ctrl+Z every time this happens  and retry and this ends up being very frustrating when doing precision work. Any idea how to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're selecting [face loops](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/faces.html#face-loops), not [edge loops](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges.html#edge-loops). See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22916/how-to-control-which-edge-loop-is-selected

Comment: Thx, corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on where you click. Click on the edge that is perpendicular to the direction you want to select. As you can see, if you click closer to the middle of a face, Blender will go with whichever edge it is closer to, so you will get "random" directions.

[image]