# Fastest way to remove an inset?

Tags: modeling

I created this inset on a cylindrical part of the model, then decided I didn't want the inset anymore. What's the easiest way to remove it? I tried Dissolving Faces and Dissolving Edges, to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Delete edge loops

1. Switch to face select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>*>Faces*)
2. Select the face loop inside the inset (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on an edge. See [How can edge rings be selected in a predictable way?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3038/599))
3. Switch to edge select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
4. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on an edge to deselect the [edge ring](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/11038/599).
5. <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd>*> Edge loops* (the menu accelerator <kbd>G</kbd> can be used for extra speed)

[image]

## Scale and remove doubles

This is only really practical if your inset is aligned to an axis. Setting up [custom axes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21249/599) and such would sorta defeat the purpose. However, if your inset *is* aligned (as it appears in your case), then this might well be faster than the first method.

1. Select the inset as shown in your screenshot
2. Scale to 0 along the Z (or whatever axis your inset is aligned to) (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> `0`)
3. <kbd>W</kbd>*> Remove Doubles*, or <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> if you use the menu accelerator.
4. <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd>*> Faces* (<kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> with the menu accelerator).

[image]

---

*Apologies in advance if the gifs are too fast. I was attempting to show what it looks like at sortof-full speed, but I'm not sure if it's possible to follow at gif framerates..*

Comment: Wow. I know I'm not supposed to use this comment for thanks, but you taught me so much more than I knew possible (e.g., menu accelerators). And the whole post is so clearly written—and illustrated! Thank you. If this comment should be deleted, hope you see it first.

Comment: @Aubrie Glad I helped :) While writing thanks in *answers* is discouraged, there's [nothing really wrong with putting meaningful feedback in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59278/238438).